# Master detail object field value

Tags: apex, trigger

Is it possible to get the data from the junction object Master detail relationship field ?
I have Session : Session Speaker : Speaker object with Session Speaker as junction.
Wanted to send an email to speaker whenever he gets tagged to a Session
Here is the trigger code

```apex
trigger SessionSpeaker on Session_Speaker__c (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update) {

    if(trigger.isInsert){
    //Call the handler class to send the email 
        for(Session_Speaker__c ss: Trigger.new){
            EmailManager.sendMail(ss.Speaker__r.Email_Address__c,'this is sandy','this is subject');
        }
    }
}
```

whereas i am getting the valued as null for email address ?
Is it not possible to get the detail record field value or need to fire a query to get the data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to query those fields.

```java
if(trigger.isInsert){
//Call the handler class to send the email 
    for(Session_Speaker__c ss: [SELECT Speaker__r.Email_Address__c FROM Session_Speaker__c WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new AND Speaker__r.Email_Address__c != null]){
        EmailManager.sendMail(ss.Speaker__r.Email_Address__c,'this is sandy','this is subject');
    }
}
```

It would be good moving the logic in an handler class (as the comment says).
If you don't have already followed the [Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers) trailhead, I would suggest to give it a try.